# How to test for significance of variance across multiple categories?

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, binary-data, chi-squared-test

I have the following (dummy) distribution:

```
+---------------+----------------------+-------------------+
| Type of Sport | No History of Injury | History of injury |
+---------------+----------------------+-------------------+
| Archery       |                   88 |               111 |
| Badminton     |                  467 |               225 |
| Basketball    |                  396 |               463 |
| Bowling       |                  374 |                 7 |
| Canoeing      |                  393 |               128 |
| Diving        |                  143 |               431 |
| Fencing       |                  372 |               456 |
| Fishing       |                  488 |               293 |
| Football      |                  308 |               434 |
| Golf          |                  475 |               363 |
| Gymnastics    |                  282 |               294 |
| Hiking        |                  147 |                39 |
| Hockey        |                  387 |               201 |
| Kickboxing    |                  303 |               209 |
| Polo          |                  327 |               470 |
| Rugby         |                  209 |                81 |
| Running       |                  282 |                38 |
| Sailing       |                   54 |               137 |
| Shooting      |                  377 |               217 |
| Skating       |                   45 |               110 |
| Skiing        |                   71 |               177 |
| Snowboarding  |                   18 |               295 |
| Squash        |                  222 |               225 |
| Surfing       |                  352 |               158 |
| Swimming      |                  311 |               344 |
| Taekwondo     |                  495 |               244 |
| Tennis        |                  421 |               333 |
| Volleyball    |                   98 |               100 |
| Walking       |                    8 |               355 |
| Windsurfing   |                  480 |               469 |
+---------------+----------------------+-------------------+
```

This distribution shows a simple count of responses to the questions:

1. 'What is your favorite sport' and
2. 'do you have a history of injury'

With the hypothesis being that 'history of injury' (IV) may affect the respondent's favorite sport (DV).

Consequently I would like to test this distribution to see if there is a significant difference between the distributions of 30 types of sports played between 'No History of Injury' and 'History of Injury'.

What is the most suitable statistical test for testing for significance in variance of distributions across multiple types of sports?